# How can I change y ticks using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have subplots, I want to change y ticks of only one plot from 0.1 to 10, therefore multiplying 10 to each y ticks.
I tried to set using `set_yticks([0, 10, 20, ..])` but somehow all the numbers get squished to the top. Is there any way?

[image]

Comment: instead of `set_ticks` try `set_yticklabels`. `set_yticks` changes where the actual tick marks are placed in your chart coordinates (hence it squishes your numbers which are allow actually below `1`). `set_yticklabels` only changes the numbers printed next to those marks.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels.html), this will leave the tick marks where they are but change the labels. Example usage:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12,6))
axs[0].set_yticklabels(np.linspace(0, 6, len(axs[0].get_yticks())))
plt.show()
```

[image]